Output from computer info Powershell script: convert from columns to rows in csv
I have to be missing something obvious, this task shouldn't be this hard! Thanks in advance if you can point it out to me without laughing too much. I'm writing a system survey script, to run on each computer in my domain on boot via GPO. Each time it runs it should add a row with all the info it gathers to a csv file on a shared drive. I can only get it to output in columns.
Code:
$loglocation = "C:\Temp"
$timestamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
$ipaddress = Get-NetIPAddress | fl -Property ipaddress | Out-String -stream | 
Select-String 10.15

# Add info to hashtable
$computerinfohastable = [ordered]@{
Timestamp = $timestamp
Hostname = hostname
OSName = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
OSVer = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
IPAddress = ($ipaddress -replace "ipaddress : ").Trim()
    }

# Convert to object
$computerinforows = $computerinfohastable.Keys | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Property = $_
    Value = $computerinfohastable[$_]
}
}

# Output to csv
$computerinforows | Export-Csv -Path "$loglocation\testfile.csv" -
NoTypeInformation -Append

What I get:
Property    Value 
Timestamp   11/25/2024 14:23 
Hostname    ##### 
OSName      Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise 
OSVer       10.0.26100 
IPAddress   nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn

What I want:
Timestamp          Hostname  OSName                             OSVer          IPAddress 
11/25/2024 14:23   #####     Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise    10.0.26100     nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn

I have been hitting up the internet and tried several methods for transposing, no success. Appreciate any advice.

Omit intermediary $computerinfohastable = [ordered]@{ … }, use
$computerinforows = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Timestamp = $timestamp
    Hostname = hostname
    OSName = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
    OSVer = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
    IPAddress = ($ipaddress -replace "ipaddress : ").Trim()
}

If you insist on intermediary $computerinfohastable = [ordered]@{ … }, use a simple casting as follows:
$computerinforows = [PSCustomObject]$computerinfohastable

In both variants, you should get
$computerinforows | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation


"Timestamp","Hostname","OSName","OSVer","IPAddress"
"11/25/2024 14:23","hostname","Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise","10.0.26100","nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn"



This is great, thank you! I will go back to references so I can understand better and use this in the future.
